# What (linux) directories are written to most/constantly?

Tags: linux, flash

When I read articles on running Linux from a flash drive, many recommend that directories that see many or constant writes be mounted in ram (e.g. as tmpfs). My question is - Which directories will these typically be, and is there any way to monitor disk activity that would show which directories see many writes?

Comment: hmm... /var and /proc? 

Can't give you a list complete enough to qualify as an answer, but that's what seems logical at first glance.

Comment: Also, `/tmp` earns a few frequent flyer miles.

Comment: The swap partitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc` is generally a [procfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) system which doesn't live in disk. So I wouldn't worry about that.

The obvious one would be `/tmp` -- this is where any temporary files that get generated are going to be stored.

`/var/run` and `/var/lock` can be mounted as tmpfs since they do not need to persist over a reboot.

`/var/log` could be a possibility as well as long as you are OK not keeping logs over a system reboot.

Answer (score 1):

`/var` and `/tmp` are obvious candidates.

[Ksfmd](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/124903) may be of help (I don't have direct experience with it, but it seems to have the potential to help you monitor your system to decide what gets mounted where).

You might be able to build a more exact match to what you want to do with the [inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html) toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

The new utility **fatrace** can show you exactly. See: https://launchpad.net/fatrace/

```
sudo fatrace
```

For example:

```
# sudo fatrace
chrome(6514): W /home/xxxx/.config/google-chrome/Default/Current Session
chrome(6514): R /home/xxxx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db
chrome(6514): R /home/xxxx/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db
chrome(6514): W /home/xxxx/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_1
chrome(6514): RW /home/xxxx/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_0
chrome(6514): W /home/xxxx/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/data_1
wicd(29613): RO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
ifconfig(29613): R /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
ifconfig(29613): CO /etc/ld.so.cache
```